# Passing data without using cookies in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to pass data between pages without using cookies and a server-side language in javascript?  every way I found incorporates cookies or a server-side language (PHP session vars).

Comment: AJAX? Can you tell us a little more about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: AJAX doesn't need user interaction. It stands for Asynchronous Javascript And Xml. It's just a method to fetch data asyncronously from a server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it through a query string.

This link will give you the code to get it using JavaScript.

http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/JavaScript-QueryString-ParseGet-QueryString-with-Client-Side-JavaScript.aspx

code snippet from the page:

```
function getQuerystring(key, default_)
{
  if (default_==null) default_="";
  key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
  var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
  if(qs == null)
    return default_;
  else
    return qs[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always add data to the url query string when you navigate, like:

```
/site/page2?username=foo&bar=110
```

Of course you have to recognize that users can manipulate those values so some kind of validation will still be necessary when the new page loads and uses those values.